# Spark specify multiple column conditions for dataframe join

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

How to give more column conditions when joining two dataframes. For example I want to run the following :

```
val Lead_all = Leads.join(Utm_Master,  
    Leaddetails.columns("LeadSource","Utm_Source","Utm_Medium","Utm_Campaign") ==
    Utm_Master.columns("LeadSource","Utm_Source","Utm_Medium","Utm_Campaign"),
"left")
```

I want to join only when these columns match. But above syntax is not valid as cols only takes one string. So how do I get what I want.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

There is a Spark [column/expression API join](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.scala#L514) for such case:

```scala
Leaddetails.join(
    Utm_Master, 
    Leaddetails("LeadSource") <=> Utm_Master("LeadSource")
        && Leaddetails("Utm_Source") <=> Utm_Master("Utm_Source")
        && Leaddetails("Utm_Medium") <=> Utm_Master("Utm_Medium")
        && Leaddetails("Utm_Campaign") <=> Utm_Master("Utm_Campaign"),
    "left"
)
```

The `<=>` operator in the example means "[Equality test that is safe for null values](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.scala#L320)".

The main difference with simple [Equality test](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.scala#L132) (`===`) is that the first one is safe to use in case one of the columns may have null values.

Comment: Could you explain what's the difference between `===` and `<=>`?

Comment: Updated with more information about difference between those equality tests.

Comment: Aha, couldn't find this in documentation. How did you know about this ?

Comment: @user568109 I am using Java API, and there are some cases when Column/Expression API is the only option. Also, Column/Expression API is mostly implemented as a Builder, so it is easier to discover new methods on each version of Spark.

Comment: This gave me duplicated columns so I used the Seq method I added in another answer.

Comment: I get this error when using `<=>` instead of `===`. **Use the CROSS JOIN syntax to allow cartesian products between these relations.;**

Comment: IMO ( and based on experience ) spark joins on multiple cols having the same names is buggy, because of all the reflections and guessing occurring in the Analytics Engine during run-time => better to use aliases with different names whenever possible ...

Answer (score 22):

As of Spark version 1.5.0 (which is currently unreleased), you can join on multiple DataFrame columns.  Refer to [SPARK-7990: Add methods to facilitate equi-join on multiple join keys](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-7990).

**Python**

```
Leads.join(
    Utm_Master, 
    ["LeadSource","Utm_Source","Utm_Medium","Utm_Campaign"],
    "left_outer"
)
```

**Scala**

*The question asked for a Scala answer, but I don't use Scala.  Here is my best guess....*

```
Leads.join(
    Utm_Master,
    Seq("LeadSource","Utm_Source","Utm_Medium","Utm_Campaign"),
    "left_outer"
)
```

Comment: how do we make the join ignore the values case (i.e. make it case insensitive)? i tried below, and did not work. sqlContext.sql("set spark.sql.caseSensitive=false")

Answer (score 8):

One thing you can do is to use raw SQL:

```
case class Bar(x1: Int, y1: Int, z1: Int, v1: String)
case class Foo(x2: Int, y2: Int, z2: Int, v2: String)

val bar = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(
    Bar(1, 1, 2, "bar") :: Bar(2, 3, 2, "bar") ::
    Bar(3, 1, 2, "bar") :: Nil))

val foo = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(
    Foo(1, 1, 2, "foo") :: Foo(2, 1, 2, "foo") ::
    Foo(3, 1, 2, "foo") :: Foo(4, 4, 4, "foo") :: Nil))

foo.registerTempTable("foo")
bar.registerTempTable("bar")

sqlContext.sql(
    "SELECT * FROM foo LEFT JOIN bar ON x1 = x2 AND y1 = y2 AND z1 = z2")
```

Comment: This is the method I use right now. I was hoping I can do it without registering as temp tables. If there is no way to do this with dataframe API I will accept the answer.

Comment: If so @rchukh's answer is much better.

Answer (score 8):

The `===` options give me duplicated columns. So I use `Seq` instead.

```
val Lead_all = Leads.join(Utm_Master,
    Seq("Utm_Source","Utm_Medium","Utm_Campaign"),"left")
```

Of course, this only works when the names of the joining columns are the same.

Answer (score 7):

**Scala:**

```
Leaddetails.join(
    Utm_Master, 
    Leaddetails("LeadSource") <=> Utm_Master("LeadSource")
        && Leaddetails("Utm_Source") <=> Utm_Master("Utm_Source")
        && Leaddetails("Utm_Medium") <=> Utm_Master("Utm_Medium")
        && Leaddetails("Utm_Campaign") <=> Utm_Master("Utm_Campaign"),
    "left"
)
```

**To make it case insensitive**,

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{lower, upper}
```

then just use `lower(value)` in the condition of the join method.

Eg: `dataFrame.filter(lower(dataFrame.col("vendor")).equalTo("fortinet"))`

Answer (score 6):

In **Pyspark** you can simply specify each condition separately:

```
val Lead_all = Leads.join(Utm_Master,  
    (Leaddetails.LeadSource == Utm_Master.LeadSource) &
    (Leaddetails.Utm_Source == Utm_Master.Utm_Source) &
    (Leaddetails.Utm_Medium == Utm_Master.Utm_Medium) &
    (Leaddetails.Utm_Campaign == Utm_Master.Utm_Campaign))
```

Just be sure to use operators and parenthesis correctly.

Answer (score 2):

In **Pyspark**, using parenthesis around each condition is the key to using multiple column names in the join condition.

```
joined_df = df1.join(df2, 
    (df1['name'] == df2['name']) &
    (df1['phone'] == df2['phone'])
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Spark SQL supports join on tuple of columns when in parentheses, like

```
... WHERE (list_of_columns1) = (list_of_columns2)
```

which is a way shorter than specifying equal expressions (=) for each pair of columns combined by a set of "AND"s.

For example:

```
SELECT a,b,c
FROM    tab1 t1
WHERE 
   NOT EXISTS
   (    SELECT 1
        FROM    t1_except_t2_df e
        WHERE (t1.a, t1.b, t1.c) = (e.a, e.b, e.c)
   )
```

instead of

```
SELECT a,b,c
FROM    tab1 t1
WHERE 
   NOT EXISTS
   (    SELECT 1
        FROM    t1_except_t2_df e
        WHERE t1.a=e.a AND t1.b=e.b AND t1.c=e.c
   )
```

which is less readable too especially when list of columns is big and you want to deal with NULLs easily.

Comment: is it really working? is this supported in 1.6 version?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
val rccJoin=dfRccDeuda.as("dfdeuda")
.join(dfRccCliente.as("dfcliente")
,col("dfdeuda.etarcid")===col("dfcliente.etarcid") 
&& col("dfdeuda.etarcid")===col("dfcliente.etarcid"),"inner")
```