# perform join on multiple DataFrame in spark

Tags: scala, join, apache-spark

I have 3dataframes generated from 3 different processes.
Every dataframe is having columns of same name.
My dataframe looks like this

```
id   val1    val2       val3    val4
 1    null   null       null    null
 2    A2      A21       A31      A41

id   val1      val2       val3      val4
 1    B1        B21        B31       B41
 2    null      null       null      null

id   val1     val2       val3    val4
 1    C1       C2        C3       C4
 2    C11      C12       C13      C14
```

Out of these 3 dataframes, i want to create two dataframes, (final and consolidated).
For final, order of preferences -
dataFrame 1 > Dataframe 2 > Dataframe 3

If a result is there in dataframe 1(val1 != null), i will store that row in final dataframe.

My final result should be :

```
id  finalVal1    finalVal2   finalVal3   finalVal4 
1     B1           B21         B31         B41
2     A2           A21         A31         A41
```

Consolidated Dataframe will store results from all 3.

How can i do that efficiently?

Comment: Could you please provide the expected output using the dataframes described above ?

Comment: Added final output required

Comment: Is it correct that you either have no `null` or a full line? Is the id in the dataset when the row is null?

Comment: Yeah..I can either have null or full line.. Id would be in dataset when whole row is  null

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear for me (you say yes, but your statement contradict mine). Do lines like  `1     B1           null         B31         B41` exist? And in this case, do you reject the whole line or do you accept non-null values?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31240148/spark-specify-multiple-column-conditions-for-dataframe-join this question has a generalised answer here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, for each row you want to find out the first non-null values, first by looking into the first table, then the second table, then the third table.

You simply need to join these three tables based on the `id` and then use the `coalesce` function to get the first non-null element

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df1 = sc.parallelize(Seq(
    (1,null,null,null,null),
    (2,"A2","A21","A31", "A41"))
  ).toDF("id", "val1", "val2", "val3", "val4")

val df2 = sc.parallelize(Seq(
    (1,"B1","B21","B31", "B41"),
    (2,null,null,null,null))
  ).toDF("id", "val1", "val2", "val3", "val4")

val df3 = sc.parallelize(Seq(
    (1,"C1","C2","C3","C4"),
    (2,"C11","C12","C13", "C14"))
  ).toDF("id", "val1", "val2", "val3", "val4")

val consolidated = df1.join(df2, "id").join(df3, "id").select(
  df1("id"),
  coalesce(df1("val1"), df2("val1"), df3("val1")).as("finalVal1"),
  coalesce(df1("val2"), df2("val2"), df3("val2")).as("finalVal2"),
  coalesce(df1("val3"), df2("val3"), df3("val3")).as("finalVal3"),
  coalesce(df1("val4"), df2("val4"), df3("val4")).as("finalVal4")
)
```

Which gives you the expected output

```
+---+----+----+----+----+
| id|val1|val2|val3|val4|
+---+----+----+----+----+
|  1|  B1| B21| B31| B41|
|  2|  A2| A21| A31| A41|
+---+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: will it work if the value in all the tables are null. I want to get null if value in all 3 is null?

Comment: Yes, `coalesce` return the first non-null values, or null if everything is null

Comment: ```consolidated = df1.join(df2, "id").join(df3, "id")```

I have seen this solution and it seems very good for multplie joins. 

Is it possible to make it for N-amount of tables. 
Because in my case i have a list of data sets which I need to join, but I do not know how many data sets there will be in the list (comes from user). 

Is it possible to make it more generic ?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: New solution with partially null lines. It avoids joins, but uses a window function and a distinct...

```
case class a(id:Int,val1:String,val2:String,val3:String,val4:String)

val df1 = sc.parallelize(List(
a(1,null,null,null,null),
a(2,"A2","A21","A31","A41"),
a(3,null,null,null,null))).toDF()

val df2 = sc.parallelize(List(
a(1,"B1",null,"B31","B41"),
a(2,null,null,null,null),
a(3,null,null,null,null))).toDF()

val df3 = sc.parallelize(List(
a(1,"C1","C2","C3","C4"),
a(2,"C11","C12","C13","C14"),
a(3,"C11","C12","C13","C14"))).toDF()

val anyNotNull = df1.columns.tail.map(c => col(c).isNotNull).reduce(_ || _)

val consolidated = {
  df1
    .filter(anyNotNull)
    .withColumn("foo",lit(1))
    .unionAll(df2.filter(anyNotNull).withColumn("foo",lit(2)))
    .unionAll(df3.filter(anyNotNull).withColumn("foo",lit(3)))
}

scala> finalDF.show()
+---+----+----+----+----+
| id|val1|val2|val3|val4|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
+---+----+----+----+----+
|  1|  B1|null| B31| B41|
|  1|  B1|  C2| B31| B41|
|  3| C11| C12| C13| C14|
|  2|  A2| A21| A31| A41|
|  2|  A2| A21| A31| A41|
+---+----+----+----+----+

val w = Window.partitionBy('id).orderBy('foo)

val coalesced = col("id") +: df1.columns.tail.map(c => first(col(c),true).over(w).as(c))
val finalDF = consolidated.select(coalesced:_*).na.drop.distinct

scala> finalDF.show()
+---+----+----+----+----+
| id|val1|val2|val3|val4|
+---+----+----+----+----+
|  1|  B1|  C2| B31| B41|
|  3| C11| C12| C13| C14|
|  2|  A2| A21| A31| A41|
+---+----+----+----+----+
```

---

Old solution:

If you have only full lines of `null` or no null at all, you can do this (edit: the advantage over the other solution is that you avoid the distinct)

data:

```
case class a(id:Int,val1:String,val2:String,val3:String,val4:String)

val df1 = sc.parallelize(List(
a(1,null,null,null,null),
a(2,"A2","A21","A31","A41"),
a(3,null,null,null,null))).toDF()
val df2 = sc.parallelize(List(
a(1,"B1","B21","B31","B41"),
a(2,null,null,null,null),
a(3,null,null,null,null))).toDF()
val df3 = sc.parallelize(List(
a(1,"C1","C2","C3","C4"),
a(2,"C11","C12","C13","C14"),
a(3,"C11","C12","C13","C14"))).toDF()
```

consolidated:

```
val consolidated = {
  df1.na.drop.withColumn("foo",lit(1))
  .unionAll(df2.na.drop.withColumn("foo",lit(2)))
  .unionAll(df3.na.drop.withColumn("foo",lit(3)))
}

scala> consolidated.show()
+---+----+----+----+----+---+
| id|val1|val2|val3|val4|foo|
+---+----+----+----+----+---+
|  2|  A2| A21| A31| A41|  1|
|  1|  B1| B21| B31| B41|  2|
|  1|  C1|  C2|  C3|  C4|  3|
|  2| C11| C12| C13| C14|  3|
|  3| C11| C12| C13| C14|  3|
+---+----+----+----+----+---+
```

Final

```
val w = Window.partitionBy('id).orderBy('foo)
val finalDF = consolidated
  .withColumn("foo2",rank().over(w))
  .filter('foo2===1)
  .drop("foo").drop("foo2")

scala> finalDF.show()
+---+----+----+----+----+
| id|val1|val2|val3|val4|
+---+----+----+----+----+
|  1|  B1| B21| B31| B41|
|  3| C11| C12| C13| C14|
|  2|  A2| A21| A31| A41|
+---+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Your solution is way too complicated and OP doesn't have a third row in his example, it is confusing

Comment: I don't see the problem of improving the coverage of the test example. OP asks for a performant solution, not a simple one.

Comment: It is confusing. You think that using a window function, distinct, filter, drop, map/reduce, a case class, etc. is more efficient than a join with coalesce ?

Comment: filter and na.drop don't require shuffle, and so are much faster than joins. The map-reduce is executed on a very small collection (the columns) and is also very fast. Piping joins creates frightening execution plans. I don't understand why you argue subjectively on stackoverflow ("it is confusing").

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of joining six tables/dataframes (not using SQL)

retail_db is a well known sample DB,  anyone can get it from Google

Problem:   //Get all customers from TX who bought fitness items

```
 val df_customers = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost/retail_db?useSSL=false").option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").option("dbtable", "customers").option("user", "root").option("password", "root").load()
  val df_products = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost/retail_db?useSSL=false").option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").option("dbtable", "products").option("user", "root").option("password", "root").load() 
  val df_orders = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost/retail_db?useSSL=false").option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").option("dbtable", "orders"). option("user", "root").option("password", "root").load()
  val df_order_items = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost/retail_db?useSSL=false").option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").option("dbtable", "order_items").option("user", "root").option("password", "root").load()
  val df_categories = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost/retail_db?useSSL=false").option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").option("dbtable", "categories").option("user", "root").option("password", "root").load()
  val df_departments = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost/retail_db?useSSL=false").option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").option("dbtable", "departments").option("user", "root").option("password", "root").load()
  val df_order_items_all = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost/retail_db?useSSL=false").option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").option("dbtable", "order_all").option("user", "root").option("password", "root").load()



  val jeCustOrd=df_customers.col("customer_id")===df_orders.col("order_customer_id")
  val jeOrdItem=df_orders.col("order_id")===df_order_items.col("order_item_order_id")
  val jeProdOrdItem=df_products.col("product_id")===df_order_items.col("order_item_product_id")
  val jeProdCat=df_products.col("product_category_id")===df_categories.col("category_id")
  val jeCatDept=df_categories.col("category_department_id")===df_departments.col("department_id")





  df_customers.where("customer_state = 'TX'").join(df_orders,jeCustOrd).join(df_order_items,jeOrdItem).join(df_products,jeProdOrdItem).join(df_categories,jeProdCat).join(df_departments,jeCatDept).filter("department_name='Fitness'")
  .select("customer_id","customer_fname","customer_lname", "customer_street","customer_city","customer_state","customer_zipcode","order_id","category_name","department_name").show(5)
```

Answer (score -3):

If they are from three different tabels, I would use push down filters to filter them on server and use join between data frame join function to join them together.

If they are not from database tables; you can use filter and map high order function to the same parallel.