# Spark - how to merge 2 dataframes by key and de-duplicating by createdTime

Tags: apache-spark, merge, apache-spark-sql

Im new at Spark and mapreduce. I wanna ask for help that is there any elegant way to do as below.
As I have a dataframe A. 
Then I want to have dataframe R which its records is merged by specific keys between dataframe A and new dataframe B with a condition like
A’s record.createdTime < B’s record.createdTime .
thanks you guys in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join` on DataFrame to achieve desired result

In Python

`dfA.join(dfB, (dfA.key == dfB.key) & (dfA.createdTime  < dfB.createdTime) ).show()`

You can also follow [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31240148/spark-specify-multiple-column-conditions-for-dataframe-join)

Comment: how about de-duplication? do you know any way to solve if in DF B have duplicated records. I only want to take the lastest record with biggest createdTime.

Comment: You can use ```dropDuplicates``` on dfB   dfB.dropDuplicates() additionally if you want you can mention list of columns to remove duplicates on specific column. You can refer more in this link https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html#dropDuplicates(java.lang.String[]) this link is for Java you can select whichever API and version of your choice